# No way to create second X screen assigned to second graphics card

Tags: multiple-monitors, xorg, xorg.conf

It seems that the X server only allows one X screen on this PC, A second `Section "Screen" Identifier "Screen1"` does nothing but the GPU-1 and its connected monitors get to be recognized even though they can't be activated.
I'm using the following setup:

1. RTX3090 on `PCI:1:0:0` (GPU-0)

   - `DP-2`: Samsung LC49G95T
2. RTX3090 on `PCI:78:0:0` (GPU-1)

   - `HDMI-1-2`: ASUS VG27AQL1A
   - `HDMI-1-1`: ASUS XG17A

- Monitor setup should be like this: (after running the arandr script obviously throws XRandR failed error message: `XRandR failed: XRandR returned error code 1: b'xrandr: Configure crtc 4 failed\n'`)

[image: arandr]

- Using `nvidia-settings`'s configuration file after reboot it is still no use

[image: nvidia-settings]

- X screen 0 must contain `DP-2` and X screen 1, `HDMI-1-1` with `HDMI-1-2`
- `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/*` has nothing but `00-keyboard.conf` and `30-touchpad.conf`, both containing `InputClass` sections
- Have tried moving the `xorg.conf` file to `xorg.conf.d` but the bad effect still remains, both HDMI monitors can't be activated.
- I want to use the `nfancurve` script to control both GPU's fan speed, hence `"Coolbits" "4"`
- Surprisingly, connecting the three monitors into one GPU makes them available, and activating them is achievable.
- Also, replacing the identifiers `"Device0"` to `"Device1"` and vice versa makes `HDMI-1` and `HDMI-2` monitors being able to activate, but `DP-1-2` only being recognized but can't be activated. As if this machine won't allow me to use some `GPU-1`
- I suspect my `xorg.conf` lacks something (maybe EDID off?) and after some googling, there is a user that had the same "no X screen 1" problem, but after upgrading `video-nvidia` drivers could achieve X server to recognize a second X screen. Still, I'm not willing to upgrade (or downgrade) to a 'beta' driver for manjaro, also, not sure how to do that.

`/etc/X11/xorg.conf`:

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 465.31

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" 5120 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load           "dbe"
    Load           "extmod"
    Load           "type1"
    Load           "freetype"
    Load           "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Samsung"
    ModelName      "Samsung LC49G95T"
    HorizSync       357.0 - 357.0
    VertRefresh     60.0 - 240.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Asus ROG"
    ModelName      "AUS ASUS XG17A"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 255.0
    VertRefresh     48.0 - 240.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Screen          0
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
#    Option         "UseDisplayDevice" "DP-2"
#    Option         "ConnectedMonitor" "DP-2"
    Option         "Coolbits" "4"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Screen          1
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090"
    BusID          "PCI:78:0:0"
#    Option         "UseDisplayDevice" "HDMI-1-2"
#    Option         "ConnectedMonitor" "HDMI-1-2, HDMI-1-1"
    Option         "Coolbits" "4"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-5"
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "5120x1440_120 +0+0 {AllowGSYNC=Off}"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "HDMI-1-2: nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {AllowGSYNC=Off}, HDMI-1-1: nvidia-auto-select +1440+0 {rotation=left}"
    #    Option         "metamodes" "HDMI-1-1: 1920x1080_240 +2560+960 {rotation=left}, HDMI-1-2: 2560x1440_144 +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

`~/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.1.log`:
https://pastebin.com/PQZV0Hiq

Comment: I have a similar problem. If you found the solution in those 6 months, please add it as an answer. Or give a hint on how to solve it. I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @Xeizzeth I got frustrated trying many other ways, I just had to switch to Windows since it handles this feature by default. There is some info that may be useful, that Linux video drivers have a limit in resolution plus refresh rate, the more refresh rate you put the less resolution you can show on the screen. This could end somewhere. This is not the case for Windows

Answer (score 1):

I found a (possible) solution to the problem and it consists of setting nvidia-drm.modeset kernel parameter to '1', i.e. `nvidia-drm.modeset=1`, and using xrandr.
No xorg.conf is required anymore and must be deleted to not interfere with xrandr.
More on that: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/manjaro-linux-trouble-creating-additional-xscreen/200434